# How to destroy previous animation and set interval in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 6 tabs on a single HTML page which is hidden by css display:hidden , on clicking the tabs the content get visible by using display:block.

The first tab has a loop containing animation the loop is created using setInterval() method of jquery. The setInterval() method is within the click event of first tab.

The problem is that when I switch to others tabs and when I return back to the first tab(clicking the first tab) the animation start again with previous setInvertal() conflicting with the second call of setInterval() , how can i destroy any previous setInterval() and all animation as soon as i switch to other tabs.

Comment: can you please add an example of what you tried?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added your code as well so we can see what you are doing wronf and try to fix it. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can stop your animation using  jQuery [stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

[clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) Cancels repeated action which was set up using setInterval

Comment: thankx for your answer but how to call clearInterval method on tab leave I mean on tab switch.

Comment: Have you tried adding a onclick handler on your tab?